# Reading a Boolean from Oracle Database with JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

Java SE 8,
Oracle Database 11.2

I'm implementing a Boolean with Oracle SQL data type NUMBER(1). The column name is DONE.

```
SQL> SELECT QUEUE_MSG_ID FROM PROCESSED_RECORDS_EWS_BACKOUT WHERE DONE = 1;

QUEUE_MSG_ID
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
414d51205030303151303120202020204a486c6102340c2d
414d51205030303151303120202020204a486c6102160d2d
414d51205030303151303120202020204a486c611f30fe2c

SQL>
```

The Java snippet is

```
    try (
        Connection qmtDatabase = getLocalhostConnection();
        Statement selectJmsMessageIdDone = qmtDatabase.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = selectJmsMessageIdDone.executeQuery("SELECT QUEUE_MSG_ID, DONE FROM " + tableName);
        ) {
      while (resultSet.next()) {
        String jmsMessageId = resultSet.getString(1);

        BigDecimal doneBD = resultSet.getBigDecimal(2);
        // If done, then doneBD equals 1.
```

Know that `tableName.equals("PROCESSED_RECORDS_EWS_BACKOUT")` and that I've stopped on a breakpoint where `jmsMessageId.equals("414d51205030303151303120202020204a486c6102340c2d")`. Why then is

```
!(doneBD.compareTo(BigDecimal.ONE) == 0)
```

?

Comment: See [`BigDecimal::compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo-java.math.BigDecimal-).

Comment: The SQL in your Java program does not limit DONE to 1, so what would you not expect some records to come out with this value?

Comment: I have a (0,1) constraint on DONE.

Comment: I expect JDBC show show me that DONE is 1 when SQL*Plus shows me that DONE is one.

Comment: Recent JDBC drivers will correctly work when you use `ResultSet.getBoolean()` on that column (0 yields false, > 0 yields true)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem.  What value of `!(doneBD.compareTo(BigDecimal.ONE) == 0)` do you get?  I get `false`, but that's what I'd expect: `doneBD` is 1, so `doneBD.compareTo(BigDecimal.ONE)` is zero (as the values compare equal) so `!(doneBD.compareTo(BigDecimal.ONE) == 0)` is `false`.

Comment: @LukeWoodward's correct explication is what prompted me to cite the API. Please [edit] your question to clarify your revised understanding.

Comment: I wrote ` !(doneBD.compareTo(BigDecimal.ONE) == 0)`
to be concise and precise. Substituting the English translation of that expression into my question results in "Why then is doneBD not equal to one?"

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I can't explain why you get a value other than 1.